# C math not respecting declared constants

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point, printf

Stackoverflow,

I'm trying to write a (very) simple program that will be used to show how machine precision and flops effect functions around their root. My code is as follows:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    const float x = 2.2;
    float sum = 0.0;

    sum = pow(x,9) - 18*pow(x,8) + 144*pow(x,7) - 672*pow(x,6) + 2016*pow(x,5) -
     4032*pow(x,4) + 5376*pow(x,3) - 4608*pow(x,2) + 2304*x - 512;

    printf("sum = %d", sum);
    printf("\n----------\n");
    printf("x = %d", x);

    return 0;
}
```

But I keep getting that `sum` is equal to zero. At first I thought that maybe my machine wasn't respecting the level of percision, but after printing `x` I discovered that the value of `x` is changing each time I run the program and is always huge `(abs(x) > 1e6)`

I have it declared as a constant so I'm even more confused as to whats going on...

FYI I'm compiling with gcc -lm

Comment: Don't print `float`s with `%d`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
printf("sum = %d", sum);
```

`sum` is a `float`, not an `int`. You should use `%f` instead of `%d`. Same here:

```
printf("x = %d", x);
```

[Reading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) about `printf()` format specifiers may be a good idea.

Comment: Compiling with `-Wall` would help, too. If you read the warnings, at least.